# How do you tell if a user is "anonymous" in the onCreate firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Inside my `onCreate` auth cloud function for firebase handler, how can I tell if the user is anonymous, e.g. the `isAnonymous` property I get on the client in the `onAuthStateChanged` or `onIdTokenChanged` response?

```
exports.createHandler = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
  let uid = user.uid,
      isAnonymous = ????;
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that you cannot obtain this information from the Admin SDK. There is no method in the SDK which allows to get it.

The reason is that "`isAnonymous` is only a client side construct" as explained here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/127.

> `isAnonymous` is only a client side construct. If a user is created with
>   `signInAnonymously()`, this flag is set to true (client side only). For
>   example you can use createUser and just create a user without any
>   profile info (no email, phone, password, etc). Would that be
>   considered anonymous? How about if you create a user with just an
>   email? What about a custom auth user? You could also unlink all
>   providers from a non-anonymous account. Would that user become
>   anonymous?
>
> Basically, you need to apply your own criteria of what an anonymous
>   user constitutes. When you listUsers you can perhaps check that no
>   providers are linked and no email/phoneNumber is set on the user, etc.

Comment: As said in that same comment on Github, you could check that no providers are associated with the user record. A user with no identity providers upon creation is likely an anonymous user. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord#providerData

Comment: Seems link provided by Frank has changed, find UserRecord api here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#providerdata

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late but maybe this can help someone.

For me getting provider info from auth token is working fine:

context.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider

Answer (score 3):

I ve tested in Emulators and found out that anonymous user has none providerData info.

A password user onCreate trigger in functino returns

```
providerData: [
  {
    providerId: 'password',
    email: '********************',
    federatedId: '************',
    rawId: '***************',
    toJSON: [Function]
  }
]
```

A ANONYMOUS user return

```
 providerData: [],
```