# firebase auth - determine if user is anonymous

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, anonymous

I'm trying to run a script that will mark anonymous users with a flag in firestore. For that I'm getting all firebase auth users with firebase-admin's auth `listUsers`. But I'm not sure how to identify whether a user has an actual account using one of the providers or just signed-in anonymously. Via a firebase auth dashboard it's easy to see who is anonymous but not sure how to get that in code.

`UserRecord` objects returned from `listUsers()` have `providerData` array field. Each element has `providerId` So, my guess is I should somehow filter that based on whether a user has only one provider which is **anonymous**. Question is what is the `providerId` for anonymous auth? Didn't manage to find that in docs.

Comment: If I recall correctly, an anonymous user has no providers linked to it. Renaud's answer here seems to confirm that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207090/how-do-you-tell-if-a-user-is-anonymous-in-the-oncreate-firebase-cloud-function, with links to sources.

Comment: Actually found the solution which worked for my case. Guess it might work for others as well if you allow to post it.

Comment: Just checked - it's basically giving me the exact same results (whether user is anonymous) as displayed in firebase auth dashboard. So, seems accurate.